# Which guarantees does an interface provide?

Tags: go

According to “The Go Programming Language” an interface can be seen as a contract. A value that satisfies, say io.Writer, guarantees that there’s a Write method with a specific signature.

But am I right to assume that there is no guarantee as to what that method does? In the case of io.Writer, the Write method could just as well read from the p argument?

Comment: How would the compiler know what it does, or what it's supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, yes. A value implements a given interface as long as it has methods with the correct names and signatures. Whether or not those methods actually do the expected thing has to be ensured by humans.